# Secure way to store encryption keys - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I use openssl and mysql encryption trough PHP. 
Currently, I write the key in the php source code, but I think it isn't so secure. If someone gets the source (maybe FTP), encryption is broken.
So, how would you store encryption keys on Linux server? I can't use another webserver to store the key.

Comment: Books have been written about key management. It all depends on your application and organization structure what's best for your particular use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Apache.

Put the secret data into an environment variable in `/etc/apache2/envvars`, set the owner to root and the permissions to 400.

An attacker will have to compromise the server to put his hands on your key.

You can also cook up a script that asks for the secret when Apache starts (annoying, but even more secure).

Note that people with root access will **always** be able to get your key and trying to hide it from them is just a placebo.

Placebo solution:

- Make your application idle by default until you POST your key to an HTTPS page within the same application, save your key in a global variable and proceed with your business. You have to consider the PHP process' lifecycle (when the process terminates, you have to resend your key).

Comment: I haven't direct access to the shell, so I should give the key to sysadmins... definitely not a good idea :)

Comment: The sysadmins normally have access to your application as well.

Comment: @user1294101: if you don't trust your sysadmins you should change them / host the code somwhere else

Comment: Yes, I trust them, but we're talking about sensible data. I prefere not to involve them directly giving the pass.

Comment: Ok, but it's differrent if I give them or if they search in my many files to take the pass, isn'it?

Comment: Thanks for the placebo.. but it's not suitable.. I use encryption to let my user save secure records on DB.. Your solution is good for a single-user single-session application, isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarly. **You** POST the key the first time and then you can persist it between request (eg. with apc or shared memory).

Comment: I don't know that matter at all and most important I must input the key every boot.. Could I write the interface that encrypts/decrypts and then "compile" it with php hiphop?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best (according to your question and comments) bet is to just stick the keys somewhere on your directory space. Make sure they are not under www-root etc. Use appropriate file permissions (depending on your server settings).