# How to secure app.php encryption key? (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5

According to [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/encryption), Laravel supports encryption and decryption of data. It works well and is easy to set up, but my question is how secure is it really?

What if the encrypted fields in the database are compromised and then the app.php file is also compromised? Then they will have access to the encryption key.

Is there a way we can programmatically secure the encryption key from hackers?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746743/secure-way-to-store-encryption-keys-php) is certainly helpful, but I'm wondering if there is a specific method for Laravel apps. Appreciated!

Comment: It's only as good as  the code itself. Make sure you get it from a good source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel's encryption is strong, it uses the `AES` algorithm through MCrypt, which is a well known PHP extension.

If your encrypted fields AND your encryption key falls into wrong hands you're pretty much screwed and there's nothing to do about it.

Fortunately, there are ways to secure the key. First of all, don't you EVER put your key **inside** the `app.php` file. Laravel 5 makes it easier than ever to use [environments](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration). Put your key inside a `.env` file and refer to it inside your `app.php` file.

As those files lay *outside* the reach of the code you run through your `public` folder, you're good to go. If someone with bad intentions finds a way to `ssh` or `FTP` into your server, this approach won't save you but also no one else will.

I don't know what are you planning on encrypt but on the off chance you are thinking about securing passwords through encryption, please [read on](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/).

Comment: For higher security, you would need to integrate with a Hardware Security Module. This isn't an undertaking for the faint of heart and requires dedicated hardware.